# Entity Bean State after Database Migration

Tags: java, database, oracle11g, entity-bean

Does Migrating from one database to another database requires comprehensive change in the Entity Beans?
I have oracle 11g express edition and I want to move to MS Sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.Your entity class can remain the same. However, you may have to change the primary key generation strategy. You may also have to change values of some attributes of the @Column annotation.

Your tables may slightly change due to the fact that different databases have their own ways of storing data. You can regenerate the tables by editing your persistence.xml

```
<properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
</properties>
```